# Find first of a set of related records, dependent on a value in another row

Tags: sql

I have a table in which a row represents a subsection of a larger block of data.

Given an input parameter which identifies one of these rows, I would like to return a different row which represents the root record.

Specifically I would like to retrieve the first record in this set.

For example:

1. Find the row with column X value of Y.
2. Get the value A, of column Z.
3. Return the first row with column Z value of A.

What is the best way of doing this?

- Two separate queries on the original table?
- A single query on the original table?
- Construct a new view that would enable a single query?
- Something else?

Comment: Are you using a particular RDBMS (e.g. Sql Server or Oracle) or are you looking for a database-independent solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the same row, if you will not order you rows by some column, but general answer will be

```
select top 1 *
from table
where Z = (select Z from table where X = @parameter)
order by ???
```